# Shape of button in android

Tags: android, android-drawable

[How can I design this button on android it is like when someone click on my button the green portion in right top should be visible.
I know about **state_pressed** but i am unable to design this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J3HwK.png)

Comment: One solution is, rather than button, you try to use layout as button shape, and any view or layout as your green portion.

Comment: How to design this shape I am unable to design this

Comment: <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="@color/lighter_gray"
        >
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/hollow"
            android:layout_width="10dp"
            android:layout_height="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/button_background"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"/>
    </RelativeLayout>      Try this, if useful then mark as useful

Comment: do you want the green area to remain after pressing releasing? or just appear on pressing and disappear on releasing?

Comment: @Rohit do not add complete code in comment if you have an answer you are most welcome to answer .

Comment: I want it to be shown when the button is pressed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There ae many ways of above design , I don't know its a good way but it will work as per requirement

Here I create two drawable one for button radius shape and second one is dimond shape, Now you will manage visibility of diamond shape view as per your requirement for example if button click visible/gone diamond shape.

**button_round_shape.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid
        android:color="#545454" />
    <corners
        android:radius="15dp" />
</shape>
```

**dimond_shape.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item
    android:left="1dp"
    android:top="1dp"
    android:right="1dp"
    android:bottom="1dp">
    <rotate android:fromDegrees="45">
        <shape>
            <size
                android:width="5dp"
                android:height="5dp" />
            <gradient
                android:startColor="#4cd964"
                android:endColor="#4cd964" />

        </shape>
    </rotate>
</item>
</layer-list>
```

**xml layout code**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

     <RelativeLayout
         android:layout_centerInParent="true"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content">

          <Button
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:id="@+id/btn"
              android:background="@drawable/button_round_shape"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
          <Button
              android:id="@+id/btn_shape"
              android:layout_width="10dp"
              android:visibility="gone"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btn"
              android:background="@drawable/dimond_shape"
              android:layout_marginLeft="-25dp"
              android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
              android:layout_height="10dp" />
     </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**JAVA code**

```
 btn.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        switch(event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                // PRESSED

                btn_shape.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                return true; // if you want to handle the touch event
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                // RELEASED
                btn_shape.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                return true; // if you want to handle the touch event
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: It worked but can't we do it using only drawable

Comment: thanks for right tick,

yes possible but you need to design images and switch both images using selector 

refer this -https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27066231/android-using-selector-to-change-button-background-image-and-color

Answer (score 0):

In you xml file in button view just add

```
android:background="@drawable/capsule_shape"
```

name the drawable file what ever you want and add the below code in to your drawable xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">

    <corners
        android:bottomLeftRadius="30dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="30dp"
        android:radius="60dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="30dp"
        android:topRightRadius="30dp" />

    <solid android:color="#B3E5FC" />

    <padding
        android:bottom="0dp"
        android:left="0dp"
        android:right="0dp"
        android:top="0dp" />

    <size
        android:height="60dp"
        android:width="270dp" />

</shape>
```

**Note:-this is for capsule like shape you can change the width or height as per you choice**

You can see the image here[image]

UPDATED:::
I wanted to add a vector drawable to my textview that i set to act as a button

```
Drawable drawer_main = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_keyboard_arrow_down_black_24dp);


Textview  txtCompanyName.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(null, null,drawer_main, null);
```

add the textview background as you did for button in xml and you will get something like this and for state press you can use animation as on onclick listener to animate the drawable inside the textview to do any type of animation you want

Comment: what about the circle at the top corner

Comment: Oh you want to add another drawable int that view you can use setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds but i think it might not work for button if that the case use textview as a button

Comment: but what if i want to add state_pressed?

Comment: see the updated answer